# Is it correct to put arrow and bow ( weapons) in the hands of Shri Ram in Ayodhya?

Tags: ayodya

We know that the sculpure of Lord Shri Ram in Ayodhya looks like a kid, then why he holds weapons in his hands?

Why do a person holds weapons in their own home? Also the people who visit the temple are devotees, then what is the meaning of holding weapons in front of devotees?

I have not seen Lord Shri Krishna holding Sudarshana Chakra in child form.

Not sure but Lord Rama appears in front of devotees also with those weapons like in Bhadrachalam.

Comment: Sri Rama was not more than 13 years old when he got married. Before he got married he had slayed several rakshasas while accompanying Vishwamitra alongwith Lakshmana. So it is justified to depict him with weapons